# Is Narasimha versus Hiranyakashipu divine retribution versus human rage?

Tags: rituals, narasimha, homam

Would be appropriate to ask as today is Narasimha Jayanti. 
Can we look at Hiranyakashipu as our (Human) rage and Narasimha as a god who can help us to get rid of this aspect of our ego.

Comment: what is a question here?

Comment: @AADHinduism The question is about symbolism behind Narasimha and Hiranyakashipu. User is asking is it right to say that Hiranya Kashipu represent ego of human beings and God  killing that ego by taking incarnation of Narasimha.

Comment: Its possible. The rakshasa duo (hiranyaksha/hiranyakashipu, ravana/kumbhakarna, sisupala/dantavakra) are usually interpreted as embodying rajas and tamas.